# ploting filtered results from clickhouse in grafana not working

Tags: sql, match, grafana, dashboard, clickhouse

I'm really new in grafana and clickhouse, I'm trying to do a filtered dashboard in grafana with information from some CSV logs loaded on clickhouse , this is how it looks the query on clickhouse:

[image]

I want to plot that in grafana, my table name is logsb and using default db, column where looking match is LOG_INFO

At this point I'm able to visualize the information from all messages from my Table in clickhouse in grafana:

[image]
using this code:

```
SELECT
$timeSeries as t,
LOG_INFO,
count() 
logsb
FROM $table
WHERE $timeFilter
GROUP BY
    t,
    LOG_INFO
ORDER BY
    t,
    LOG_INFO
```

but I want to do a match or regex search to present in the graphic only the results from the filtering, trying something like this
[image]

```
SELECT
    $timeSeries as t,
    LOG_INFO,
    count() 
    logsb
FROM $table

WHERE $timeFilter AND match(LOG_INFO, 'cc error')
GROUP BY
    t,
    LOG_INFO
ORDER BY
    t,
    LOG_INFO
```

But is not working

I really appreciate your help on this

Thanks

Comment: What about it isn't working? Please be specific, include error message if any, or wring results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*key, value* pairs should be represented as an array of tuples:

```sql
SELECT 
    t,
    groupArray((LOG_INFO, c)) AS groupArr    
FROM (
    SELECT 
        $timeSeries as t,
        LOG_INFO,
        count() c
    FROM $table
    WHERE $timeFilter AND match(LOG_INFO, 'cc error')
    GROUP BY t, LOG_INFO
    )
GROUP BY t
ORDER BY t
```

See more details [ClickHouse datasource for Grafana](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/vertamedia-clickhouse-datasource).

Answer (score 0):

also please turn off "extrapolate" checkbox on query editor